# Bound Function / Exponential (Unit Circle)

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I need to mathematically prove the next inequality:

$$\frac{(e^{2x}-1)^2}{(e^{2x}+1)^2} \le 1$$

If I graph the function, it is bounded above by 1, I don't know however how to proceed with this mathematically. I think I need complex formulas though.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$
|{e^{2x}-1}|\le|{e^{2x}+1}|,
$$

so $$\frac{|e^{2x}-1|}{|e^{2x}+1|} \le 1$$

and by taking the square, this implies to your inequality.

Comment: that was easier than I thought, thanks a lot

Comment: You're wellcome :D